# Android Studio Editor scheme theme

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts, themes

I'm new to android studio, I watched a couple of tutorials on youtube and I saw editor theme that is very readable and beautiful, so I wanted to ask you if anybody knows which **theme** and **font** is used.

Here is the link to youtube video: https://youtu.be/TIiY1VIIQwg?t=3m2s

One more image of the theme and font:
[Google Developer Editor theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHX0l.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some awesome theme for android studio
http://www.androidstudiothemes.com/theme/github

I think it 's Github theme on a dark background.
I recommend to use this 
https://github.com/equinusocio/material-theme
Go to Android Studio > Setting > find Plugins > Search for "Material" > Install & Restart. Enjoy!

Comment: Do you maybe know which font is used?

Comment: i think it s default font however defaul font on different OS is not same! for example on ubuntu it chose Ubuntu font as default.

Comment: Is there any font for Android studio similar to Atom default font on OSX?

Comment: check out second link.

Comment: Yeah but this is only for sublime text 3 not for Android studio

Comment: it s plugin for android studio Go to Android Studio > Setting > find Plugins > Search for "Material" > Install & Restart. Enjoy!